# Disk is too full, resizing is not helping or taking effect [Google Compute Engine]

Tags: google-compute-engine

I am using Google Compute engine and I got what is commonly known issue cannot connect via ssh or any means `due to Disk is too full`. I have resized disk multiple times and even x10 but changes are visible within compute engine but ssh still won't connect and logs still says disk is full.

Is there any other ways to solve this, I have important data/mongodb in that engine ?

- resized incrementally few times, didn't help
- added additional disks, didn't help
- tried to delete some files via `startup-script`, didn't help

Some part of error messages...

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/cloud-init", line 618, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/bin/cloud-init", line 614, in main
    get_uptime=True, func=functor, args=(name, args))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cloudinit/util.py", line 1900, in log_time
    ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/bin/cloud-init", line 489, in status_wrapper
    atomic_write_json(status_path, status)
  File "/usr/bin/cloud-init", line 434, in atomic_write_json
    raise e
IOError: [Errno 28] No space left on device
Aug  5 04:46:15 backend google: startup script found in metadata.
/usr/share/google/fetch_script: line 30: echo: write error: No space left on device
Aug  5 04:46:15 backend startupscript: Running startup script /var/run/google.startup.script
Aug  5 04:46:15 backend startupscript: Finished running startup script /var/run/google.startup.script
...
accounts-from-metadata: WARNING Could not update /home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys due to Disk is too full`

Answer (score 1):

After few different attempts I was able to fix issue by:

creating snapshot of the disk and creating new instance with increased persistent storage, data is there and size of disk is increased, all set.